# Jquery load issue with countdown script

Tags: load, setinterval

I'm calling another page of mine on the same domain with ...

```
    function updTtimer()
    {
     $("#ttimer").load('chatrooms_timer.php');
    }

    setInterval( updTtimer, 30000 );
```

every 30 seconds where ttimer is a DIV and the PHP file contains a countdown script that doesn't use setInterval.

When the page first loads the countdown counts down correctly. However after the refresh occurs it counts down an incremental number of times per refresh instead of once per second. I think this has something to do with the event handler but I just can't figure out what to do about it.

Comment: The code you posted is insufficient. Please edit your question and add more relevant code, and the HTML that uses it.